# Choosing regulator for gyro's and accelerometer

Tags: power-supply, accelerometer, gyro, ldo

Should I choose a linear regulator that has good transient response? or ultra low Vrms noise? or high accuracy?

I am using digital accelerometers and gyros (BMA180 and ITG3200).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to look within linear regulators if you want to get the best performance from analog chips ("digital" accelerometers/gyros are still analog at their core), SMPS almost always have much more ripple unless you're looking at really old linear regulators with tons of input ripple

Accuracy shouldn't matter (within part tolerances) as the sensors are generally ratiometric, though as always, check the datasheet.

You want low noise, but how you minimize that depends on the broader context.  If this is battery powered there shouldn't be much input noise, so a general low-noise regulator would be best.  However, if you also have other parts on the same voltage rail (e.g. a radio) that might switch on occasionally and eat tons of current, choosing one with good transient response might be better.  If it's line driven, you may want better input rejection (if you have a terrible AC/DC supply).

The best performance you could squeeze out of them would be to put them (and other analog parts) on their own voltage supply where you would know that nothing would be switching in and out very fast, putting noise on the supply.

From my limited experience with some MEMS accelerometers five years ago, it's pretty easy to hit the noise limits of the device (though they've come way down in price and performance has probably gone up as well), so don't go overboard unless you know your supply is what ails you.

Comment: I have a wireless transciever on there which would draw heaps of current intermittently. However, can i get away with this by NEVER operating the transciever when datalogging from the sensors, and only transmit data after logging has finished?

Comment: @cksa: That would definitely help, though your MCU will also be another source of noise, but good bypass capacitors will limit it.  The interesting part of that solution is it's in software, so you could see if it actually matters without much trouble.  If you're going to avoid dual regulators, a simple LC filter for your analog circuitry may be prudent.